# How do I make CalendarView automatically scroll to today?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm using WinUI3/Windows App SDK 1.3 - XAML/C#
My problem is that most UIs today have a de facto "Today" button on their calendar controls.
In WASDK/WinUI, the control is called "CalendarView" and works great. Unfortunately, it does not have a "Today" button that when clicked, should scroll the calendar to today's date.

I already have a simple button atop the CalendarView, but looking into the documentations from Microsoft, there's no functionality for what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's the default CalendarView control:
[Exhibit A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1WJU.png)

Now here's the calendar with my button:
[Exhibit B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLTdT.png)

What I would like to do is when I click on the "Today" button, the calendar will automatically update itself to scroll into today's date. Example, the calendar is currently displaying the month of December 2050, when I click on today button, the calendar should auto-scroll back to the current month, day and year.

Any guidance or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.setdisplaydate?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-calendarview-setdisplaydate(windows-foundation-datetime)

```
CalendarView.SetDisplayDate(DateTimeOffset.Now);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the C# code, create a function to retrieve the current date and scroll the calendar view to today's date.

```
private void TodayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Get the current date
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

  // Scroll the CalendarView to today's date
  calendarView.ChangeView(today, null, null);
}
```

In the XAML code, link the "Today" button to this function.

```
<Button x:Name="TodayButton" Content="Today" Click="TodayButton_Click" />
```

Comment: Hi, the ChangeView method is nowhere to be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2, however, I found this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.setdisplaydate?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-calendarview-setdisplaydate(windows-foundation-datetime) which does the job. I appreciate your help.